# SP 2013 how to find duplicate items in a list using column filtering in a view

Tags: sharepoint-server

using List View SP 2013 how to find duplicate items in a list with same date(example:incident date column)..what to mentioned in filter field for date in list view

Comment: You can't filter duplicates. However you can group them by columns.

Comment: Sort by the field, delete any duplicates you see

Comment: thanks for the quick response.. but we cant group items by morethan 2 columns.. but I have to filter them using 3 columns